# D'où vient le ù de où ?

Tags: étymologie, pronoms, alphabet, diacritiques

Je lis que *où* est le seul mot comportant un *ù* avec un accent grave. [Le Wiktionnaire confirme cette affirmation](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/o%C3%B9). Je ne sais pas si c'est vrai, mais je n'ai effectivement pas souvenir d'avoir jamais vu un autre mot.

Mais alors, d'où vient cet accent ? Le Wiktionnaire et [le TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/o%C3%B9) se contentent de dire qu'il sert à le différencier de « *ou* ». Vraiment ? Ce n'est pourtant ni le seul homonyme, ni le seul homophone de la langue française.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'[année 1539](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/5805) coïncide étrangement avec celle de [*L'ordonnance de Villers-Cotterêt*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordonnance_de_Villers-Cotter%C3%AAts); mais celle-ci n'a pas vocation à réglementer directement l'orthographe. Mais le *où* n'est pas un cas isolé auquel on apporte une réponse isolée : cela participe plutôt d'une innovation de portée plus générale au 16<sup>e</sup> siècle. En effet, dans *Le bon usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, ed. *Boeck*; voir [aussi](http://www.guichetdusavoir.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=61428&p=117731&hilit=diacritique#p117731)), on explique au §103 que : c'est à l'imprimeur [*Robert Estienne*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Estienne)<sup>1</sup> à qui l'on doit, en 1530, l'introduction de l'accent aigu sur le [e] final; au 17<sup>e</sup> beaucoup utilisé pour marquer le [ɛ] final. Quant à l'accent de grave, on indique qu'il fut d'un emploi « restreint et incertain ». On l'utilise comme *signe diacritique* avec *à*, *là* et *où* pour [distinguer](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3696) des homonymes dès le 16<sup>e</sup>; c'est l'influence du *là* qui entraîne les autres. Mais on attribue à *Pierre Corneille* l'utilisation de l'accent aigu et grave pour marquer la [phonétique](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3694) entre [e] et [ɛ]. Au [*Guichet du savoir*](http://www.guichetdusavoir.org/viewtopic.php?f=64&t=10775&p=19169&hilit=diacritique#p19169), on trouve un bloc d'extraits du *Dictionnaire historique de l’orthographe française*, sous la direction de Nina Catach, *Larousse*, Paris, 1995 :

> " (…) la mise en place des nouveautés [typographiques](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-I/academie-accentuation.html#Accentuation) en français est
>   liée de façon incontestable à l’introduction des caractères italiens,
>   aux encouragements du roi et à l’italianisme de la cour. (…) Entre
>   1525 et 1540 environ, et de façon extraordinairement rapide, les
>   habitudes modernes des signes auxiliaires, des signes de correction et
>   de référence, des signes de ponctuation et enfin des accents,
>   pénètrent dans les éditions latines, puis françaises.
>  (…) Aucun de
>   ces signes ne semble être proprement français. Entre 1530 et 1540, ils
>   sont adoptés à Paris, en partie chez S. de Colines et R. Estienne,
>   mais surtout par de vaillants initiateurs comme Tory, Augereau, Chr.
>   Wechel… (à Lyon par Sébastien Gryphe, Estienne Dolet, G. Roville, Jean
>   de Tournes, etc.)
>  (…) C’est aux dessinateurs de lettres, graveurs
>   et fondeurs (Garamond, Granjon) que de grands imprimeurs réformateurs
>   doivent d’avoir pu répandre en France et en Europe la « maigre
>   orthographe » qui est devenue notre orthographe actuelle. "
>
> [ *Dictionnaire historique de l’orthographe française*, sous la
>   direction de Nina Catach, *Larousse*, Paris, 1995 ]

À la [*BDL*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=3692) on parle ensuite d'une régression dans l'utilisation des accents dans la première moitié du 17<sup>e</sup>; pour ensuite la voir se fixer selon l'emploi qu'on en fait aujourd'hui à la fin du 18<sup>e</sup>.

C'est généralement dans ce contexte que le *où* prend l'accent, à la date indiquée, pour distinguer des homonymes.

---

<sub>1. Parfois on fait référence à sa traduction de 1530 du [*De corrupti sermonis emendatione libellus*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=PghJAAAAcAAJ&vq=o%C3%B9&pg=PP15#v=onepage&q&f=false) de [*Cordier*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathurin_Cordier), mais l'accentuation semble à première vue très timorée sinon complètement absente (le français est intercalé avec du latin et donc difficile à lire).</sub>

Comment: Langue-fr.net: [Histoire des accents](http://www.langue-fr.net/spip.php?article104)

Comment: @mins Merci ! Je vous invite à produire une réponse en extrayant des éléments du lien en question. Plusieurs approches et plusieurs réponses et sources sont les bienvenues !

Answer (score 14):

Le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (sous la dir. d'A. Rey, ed. *Le Robert*) dit aussi que l'accent a simplement été ajouté pour le différencier de *ou* en 1539.

Comment: Merci ! Tu as un lien ?

Comment: Je n'ai pas de lien vers un site web, je n'ai que l'édition papier du dictionnaire historique de la langue française.

Comment: En tout cas merci. :)